# __str__(self) function not working for printing objects in Python

Tags: python, string, class, object, printing

I have been working on improving using classes and objects in Python but have been having trouble displaying the values of different objects in my programs. I was taught by my instructor that using the **str**(self) function will automatically be called whenever an object is passed the print() function, however, the output still shows the object's address in memory rather than the value. I have documented my code below ran it in two different compiling programs but still cannot find where my error is occurring.

```
# the class of the bank account
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, bal):
        self.__balance = bal

# deposits the amount given by the user
def deposit(self, amount):
    self.__balance += amount

# withdraws the amount given by the user
def withdraw(self, amount):
    if(self.__balance >= amount):
        self.__balance -= amount
    else:
        print("Error: Insufficient funds")

# returns the current balance of the user's account
def get_balance(self):
    return self.__balance

# sets the user's account given a specified balance
def set_balance(self, bal):
    self.__balance = bal

# prints the user's balance
def __str__(self):
    return "The balance is $" + format(self.__balance, ",.2f")

def main():
    start_bal = float(input("Enter your starting balance: ")) # retrieves balance from the user
    savings = BankAccount(start_bal) # creates an object that hold's the user's balance
    print(savings)

main()
```

instead of getting the value of the account the program outputs `<__main__.BankAccount object at 0x0000025EE6535A90>`

Please let me know of anything I can change to correct the issue. Thank you.

Comment: you have problem with formatting, need to indent defs

Comment: These functions aren't inside the class, only `__init__` is inside your class, you should format your code correctly

Comment: Thank you all were correct! However, I have a question. Do you happen to know why the functions need to be indented within the class? Why am I not able to use them correctly even though they have been declared within the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When main is call and in the print(savings) is executed it prints the str representation of BankAccount class which is the savings memory address and then since your **str** implementation is defined out side of the class it has nothing to do with the class.

try this:

```
# the class of the bank account
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, bal):
        self.__balance = bal

    # deposits the amount given by the user
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.__balance += amount

    # withdraws the amount given by the user
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if(self.__balance >= amount):
            self.__balance -= amount
        else:
            print("Error: Insufficient funds")

    # returns the current balance of the user's account
    def get_balance(self):
        return self.__balance

    # sets the user's account given a specified balance
    def set_balance(self, bal):
        self.__balance = bal

    # prints the user's balance
    def __str__(self):
        return "The balance is $" + format(self.__balance, ",.2f")

def main():
    start_bal = float(input("Enter your starting balance: ")) # retrieves balance from the user
    savings = BankAccount(start_bal) # creates an object that hold's the user's balance
    print(savings)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an indention problem, your class is defined as this only:

```
# the class of the bank account
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, bal):
        self.__balance = bal
```

Try indenting all the code below this section one indendentation block until you get to the `def main()` function, such that BankAccount gets the methods you intended it to have:

```
# the class of the bank account
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, bal):
        self.__balance = bal

    # deposits the amount given by the user
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.__balance += amount

    # withdraws the amount given by the user
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if(self.__balance >= amount):
            self.__balance -= amount
        else:
            print("Error: Insufficient funds")

    # returns the current balance of the user's account
    def get_balance(self):
        return self.__balance

    # sets the user's account given a specified balance
    def set_balance(self, bal):
        self.__balance = bal

    # prints the user's balance
    def __str__(self):
        return "The balance is $" + format(self.__balance, ",.2f")

def main():
    start_bal = float(input("Enter your starting balance: ")) # retrieves balance from the user
    savings = BankAccount(start_bal) # creates an object that hold's the user's balance
    print(savings)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite the `__str__` operator of your `BankAccount` class:

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, bal):
        self.__balance = bal

    def __str__(self):
        return "The balance is $" + format(self.__balance, ",.2f")


In [25]: start_bal = 2.3
In [27]: savings = BankAccount(start_bal) 

In [28]: print(savings)
The balance is $2.30
```

Just nest your method correctly within your class